# JavaCV converting bitmap to gray provides duplicate image output

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

I want to convert a bitmap to gray bitmap :

```java
private Bitmap toGray(Bitmap bitmap) {

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    IplImage iplImage = IplImage.create(w, h, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(iplImage.getByteBuffer());

    IplImage iplImageDest = IplImage.create(w, h, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCvtColor(iplImage , iplImageDest , CV_RGB2GRAY);

    return toBitmap(iplImageDest);
}

private static Bitmap toBitmap(IplImage iplImage) {

    int w = iplImage.width();
    int h = iplImage.height();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(iplImage.getByteBuffer());

    return bitmap;
}
```

**Output :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/btNDH.png

- Left : Original image
- Right : Generated image, problem : gray image duplicated at the top of the image and the bottom is empty.

What am I doing wrong to get this duplicated image?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using the deprecated OpenCV 1 types and constructors?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm using JavaCV v1.3.2 not directly OpenCV

Comment: shouldn't you be using `CV_RGBA2GRAY` since the image depth is 4?

Comment: I switched to CV_RGBA2GRAY, I do not see any changes..